# Merging two managed objects with core data

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, core-data

Here is the problem I am facing:

I have a Contact managed object which contains an account_id and a username. Both the username and the account_id are `unique`, but unfortunately I have no choice but tolerate sometimes only having the username, and sometimes only having the account_id.

Asynchronously, I have immediately started checking against the server to get the second part of the contact(either username, or account_id).

This leads to a potential race condition though. I can create a contact with username "Austin" but with no account id. I can at the same time create a contact with account_id: 1234. It is possible that the calls to the server will subsequently reveal that the Austin username actually has the 1234 account id and these two contact objects actually are a single contact.

*If that happens, I have the following scenario:*

```
 contact1: username = "Austin", account_id = nil, a bunch of to-many relationships 
 contact2: username = nil, account_id = "1234", a bunch of *different* to-many relationships
```

*And merge them into*

```
contact: username = "Austin", account_id="1234" and the union of all the relationships in either original contact.
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this object merge?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you recognise that the two contacts are in fact the same? Do they have the same internal id (which is not visible in your example)? Just from the data you provided this part is not clear to me ...

Comment: If they have a matching account_id they are the same. The server will guarantee that all username's are unique, all account_id's are unique, and by extension, all pairs of usernames and account_ids are unique. I actually already have the matching sorted out, I just need help with what to do once I know I need to merge them

Comment: It depends on your architecture - you could for example say that the account created on the iPhone will have the relationships added flagged as "needs to be synchronised", then when you match the account on the server update the account on the server with these "needs to be synchronised" relationships and update the account in the iPhone with the complete account from the server - by this you define the server as being the leading data source, which might be a good idea.

Comment: This isn't a question of ground truth. The server is just reporting: account_id: 1234 has username Austin, or alternatively, username Austin has account_id 1234. My question is simply how do I merge the two "half" contacts into a single contact object once I know that that is what I need to do. Unfortunately I cannot change the overall design due to business constraints in terms of synchronizing against the server first etc etc

Comment: What is the problem then? Just get the relationships from the server and add them to the contact on the iphone, and send the relationships from the iPhone to the server and add them there. Of course, you need to have (or create) the related objects on the iPhone or the server, respectively.

Comment: The server doesnt know any relationships. My question is simply "is there a quick way for me to merge all relationships and properties"... I can do it manually on a property by property basis, but that sounds like a maintenance nightmare. My whole question was "is there a correct way to do that" and I'm hoping there is a better option than manually updating each property. Especially considering that all the relationships also have inverses which would need to be updated, and none of the existing data conflicts. My hope is there is some Core Data merge method for this kind of thing.

Comment: Now I get it: the server only knows the account_id - username connection, and both objects are in your iPhone app. If it's not too much overhead you could structure your database in your app so that a contact object has an account object (which can have relationships) and a username object (which also can have relationships. The connection of both is done in the account object - with that, you don't have to copy any data, you just set the right account / username relationships in your account object.